# Accessing MySQL tables with over 10 million rows = Error: too many connection

Tags: mysql

How could I optimize this MySQL queries that is accessing two tables with more than 10 million rows each?

What the query below do is, it gets all the id from 'users' table that doesn't exist on the 'guests' table. This will return over hundred of thousands of rows as a result so we're limiting it to atleast get 5000 id per run. Is there a better way to run this so we could get more done per run.

```
    $before = date here before in time;
$now = date now;

$query="SELECT users.id 
    FROM users   
    LEFT JOIN guests ON guests.id = users.id    
    WHERE guests.id IS NULL AND (users.in >= '$before' AND users.in <= '$now')
    LIMIT 0,5000";
```

After we know which IDs doesn't exist on the guests table we have to delete those rows in the users table. So this means it will run another 5000 delete queries to delete all those IDs.

If we run this process with both tables containing over 10million rows of data our server is returning an error that it has too many connection and MySQL server can't be accessed anymore until you restart it. But if we run the same process with both tables containing over a few thousand rows, it doesn't encounter this problem but it still take some time.

Why is this happening and how could we avoid this at the same time optimize this process altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things - check how your software handles MySQL connections. Looks like it opens a persistent connection, and then does not reuse it, and there is a new connect before every query.

Second - you can modify your query to do it in one statement, instead of running a separate query on each user. That way only one connection is needed, and all the processing will be on MySQL side, which will be able to optimize it further.

Edit: One more thing that you can check is running `EXPLAIN` on your query to make sure you have all the proper index set up (if select part is running slow now).

Comment: It's not using persistent connection. What boggles me is that in the list of processes for MySQL there are a lot of SELECT queries after my main SQL query posted above. This select queries are selecting the IDs in the guest table. Does LEFT JOIN or any JOIN statement do a sub-select query? Is it possible that the LEFT JOIN is causing the "too many connection" error?

Comment: @officeboi - no, that would not be possible. What software/language/library are you using for this? It might be that your library is retrieving additional info via separate selects... And it might be that the same lib is causing extra connects...

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** test this query before running on live data. I do not claim responsibility for any data lost

```
DELETE 
  u
FROM
  users AS u 
LEFT JOIN
  guests AS g 
ON g.id = u.id
WHERE 
  g.id IS NULL 
  AND (users.in >= '$before' AND users.in <= '$now')
```

As to the core of your question (too many connections) I suspect your PHP script is starting new connections in loop for ever ID that is to be deleted.

Comment: I made a simple PHP test script just to get the IDs in the user table that doesn't exist in the guest table. This is a normal - Connect using normal connection (not persistent) then SELECT using the SQL query above then disconnect the connection and use PHP to output the result. I'm still encountering the same problem it is giving me the "Too many connections" error. I've even limited the result to 2500 and it's still the same. Also no one can access the MySQL DB while the script is running. Is it possible the JOIN statement is doing a sub-select causing the too many connection error?

Comment: No. One query runs within one connection. It does not create additional connections for subqueries etc.